# Deployed MVC application does not connect to database

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, connection-string, database-connection

My application is working correctlywhen I debug it against my sql express.
Now i have deployed on IIS on another machine with win2008 web server and changed the database connection string.

I would like that the application uses always the same user to connect to the database and not to use the identity of the connected user.

the error I get is

```
Error: Cannot open database "XXXXXX" requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE'
```

how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

without knowing what your current connection string is, have a look at this site for some guidance into various connection string settings: http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008. It's as simple as setting up a sql account in the database itself and then using that username/password in the connection string like this:

```
Data Source=myServerAddress;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use SQL Authentication, you can specify the username and password as part of the connection string. You can even encrypt this information in the Web.Config file so you won't worry about people looking at it.

If you can't use SQL Authentication (most government agency security settings require this to be disabled) you can use the credentials of the Application Pool Identity used to run your web application. It looks like this is what's happening for you and that you're using the default Network Service credential. If no credential was being used you'd get Login failed for user '' or possibly Anonymous User if using Sql Profiler.

Try changing the application pool identity account to a real user that has access to your database.